# How to convert JSON into textoutput without the attributes

Tags: json, text, logstash

I am trying to log messages in the `"output.txt"` which are more readable.

So if my input data is like {"attr1":"val1","attr2":"val2"}

I want to write it in the log as:

`val1 | val2` (without attr1 , attr2 like a string)

Basically converting data from JSON to a readable format.

What should I be modifying in my Logstash configuration to do that? Below is my conf file

```
    input { file
    {
      path => "input.log"
      codec => 
     multiline {
     pattern => "^Test*"
     negate => "true" 
     what =>  "next"
       }
      }
      }


         output {
        file {
     path => "output.txt"
     message_format => "%{[message]}"

      }
        }`
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the multiline codec? If your input data indeed has the form `{"attr1":"val1","attr2":"val2"}` then it'll never match the regexp in the codec.

Comment: My input data is as below : Test: line1
line2:
line3
line4  what i had mentioned is the current output format in the output.txt..i had by mistake mentioned it as input data

Comment: So while receiving the input, i am merging all the lines that start with Test into a single line and then trying to format the output

Comment: I still don't get it. What's the current output from Logstash, or alternatively, what does the `message´ field look like?

Comment: **Input file:** Test : New socket
 ABC_OpenJava
_ciaHost ........ null
_iaHost...........null
Test :ADV_Base
**Expected final output:**
Test  New socket ABC_OpenJava:_ciaHost null,_iaHost null
Test ADV_Base
**But currently it is coming in output.txt**
{"@timestamp":"2015-07-08T18:56:12.026Z","message":"Test :New socket\nABC_OpenJava:\n_ciaHost ........ null\n_iaHost ......... nulll"@version":"1","tags":["multiline"],"host":"test.com","path":"input.log"}
{"@timestamp":"2015-07-08T18:56:12.030Z","message":"Test:ADV_Base","@version":"1","tags":["multiline"],"host":"test.com","path":"input.log"}

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `line` codec and specify a `format` string with the [sprintf format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#sprintf)

```
output {
    file{
        codec =>
            line {
                format = "%{val1}|%{val2}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```